# Find the Integral: $\int\limits_{0}^{\pi/6} \sin{x}\cos^2 x\,\mathrm dx$

Tags: calculus

Find the Integral:

> $$\int\limits_{0}^{\pi/6}\sin{x}\cos^2{x}\,\mathrm dx$$

The answer is 1/3- square root of 3 over 8.

What method should one use to solve a problem like this?¨

[image]

Comment: Try a $u$-substitution.

Comment: Substitution (set $u=\cos x$).

Comment: @Cetshwayo - unless you are specifically not allowed to use substitution, that would seem like the obvious method.

Comment: You missed the negative sign when performing substitution in your work. Also, your work has flaws in the sense that you left the limits unchanged after substitution. You got the answer right since you wrote it back in terms of $x$ before evaluation of the definite integral.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\int_0^{\pi/6} \sin x \cos^2 x \,dx = \int_0^{\pi/6} (\cos x)^2 \sin x \,dx$$

Putting $u = \cos x,$ we get $du = -\sin x\,dx \iff \sin x \,dx = -du$

And at $x = \pi/6$, $u = \cos(\pi/6) = \sqrt 3/2$. At $x=0, u = \cos 0 = 1$.

That gives us $$\int_0^{\pi/6} (\cos x)^2 (\sin x \,dx) = \int_1^{\sqrt 3/2} u^2 (-du)= -\int_1^{\sqrt 3/2} u^2\,du = -u^3/3\Big|_1^{\sqrt 3/2}$$

Now evaluate the result at the limits of integration.

Answer (score 5):

$$u=\cos x\implies \mathrm du = (-\sin x)\,\mathrm dx$$

$$I=\int\limits_{\sqrt{3}/2}^{1}u^2\,\mathrm du$$

Can you continue?

Comment: Let me give it another try.

Comment: I just added a picture of my work can you tell me where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** let $I=\int \:sin\left(x\right)cos^2\left(x\right)dx$

> So we'll have: $I=\int\:sin\left(x\right)\cdot cos^2\left(x\right)dx=-cos^3\left(x\right)-2\int \:cos^2\left(x\right)sin\left(x\right)dx$

Therefore: $3I=-cos^3\left(x\right) + C$ which led to $I=\frac{-cos^3\left(x\right)}{3} + C$. I think you can continue from here. This is another easiest method, if you don't like substitution. Where you don't understand ask me.

Comment: To obtain $\sin x$, type \sin x in math mode.  For $\cos x$, type \cos x in math mode.